# NumberFormatException for Long.parseLong

Tags: java, exception, long-integer, numberformatexception

when I try to run this Code (yes, I know it will run horribly long and is not very pretty):

```
DecimalFormat formatA = new DecimalFormat("000");
        DecimalFormat formatB = new DecimalFormat("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

        for(int c=0; c<=7; c++){
            String binC = formatA.format(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(c)));
            for(int d=0; d<LFSRa.length; d++){
                LFSRa[d]=Character.getNumericValue((binC.charAt(d)));                   
            }
            for(long e=0; e<=1099511627775L; e++){
                String binE = formatB.format(Long.parseLong((Long.toBinaryString(e))));
                for(int f=0; f<LFSRb.length; f++){
                    LFSRb[f]=Character.getNumericValue((binE.charAt(f)));
                }


            }
        }
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000000000000000"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at A41.main(A41.java:76)
```

and I don't get why. What should I do?
Could somebody explain the problem to me?

Comment: Once your binary number has 20 digits, reinterpreting it in decimal will exceed the max value of a `Long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you see this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

The range of long i.e. max is 9223372036854775807, 19 digits and once it reaches 10000000000000000000 (20 digits), it will try to convert this string to long which is out of range and hence you get an exception.